# Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFoundError --> No module named 'sql'

Tags: python, oracle, module, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda 3 to run Python but unable to run certain Python code.

Below is the first cell of the Python code and the first 2 rows of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dQAG.jpg)

Below is the remaining error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWNSE.jpg)

Summary of the error message (1st and last row):
  ModuleNotFoundError
    .
    .
    .
  No module named 'sql'

What am I missing here? I can run some simpler Python code but unable to run more complex ones.

I think the main difference between the 2 Python scripts is this:
   %load_ext sql
This particular line of script is not in the simpler Python code.

Thanks guys!

PS Database is Oracle

Answer (score 2):

My colleague has just resolved this issue for me.

I actually commented out this bit --> "%load_ext sql" and it ran but then we are not sure what it would affect and hence we resolved it properly.

Basically, open up the Anaconda Prompt and run "pip install ipython-sql" <-- this would install this module/thing required.

If you also come across issue related to cx_oracle. In the same command prompt and run "pip install cx_oracle"